# How do I clone a java keystore instance?

Tags: java, instance, clone, keystore

I would like to clone a java keystore instance.

I wrote the master keystore to a ByteArrayOutputStream and flushed it to a byte array. I then created a new keystore instance and loaded from the byteArray as ByteArrayInputStream. It worked fine. Just wondering if there is a better way to do it.

I couldn't find any examples of doing this. In the event that I am doing it the right way, I thought posting it would at-least help someone who wants to do something similar.

```java
public static void test() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException
    {
        KeyStore originalKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "JCEKS");
        originalKeyStore.load( null, "1234".toCharArray());
        Key originalKey = generateNewKey();
        originalKeyStore.setKeyEntry( "keyAlias", originalKey, "1234".toCharArray(), null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        originalKeyStore.store( os, "1234".toCharArray());

        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( os.toByteArray());
        KeyStore clonedKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "JCEKS");
        clonedKeyStore.load( is, "1234".toCharArray());
        Key clonedKey = clonedKeyStore.getKey( "keyAlias", "1234".toCharArray());

        String encodedOriginalKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( originalKey.getEncoded());
        String encodedClonedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( clonedKey.getEncoded());

        System.out.println( "Original key:" + encodedOriginalKey);
        System.out.println( "ClonedKey:" + encodedClonedKey);
        System.out.println( "Key equality:" + encodedClonedKey.compareTo( encodedOriginalKey));
    }

    public static Key generateNewKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance( "AES");
        kgen.init( 256, new SecureRandom());
        return kgen.generateKey();
    }
```

Comment: If your code is working, this seems like a question for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Michael Thanks. Did not know that existed.

Answer (score -2):

by deep clone you can make copy of almost everything.

deep copy code

```
public static Object clone(Object o) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream BAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream OOS = new ObjectOutputStream(BAOS);
        OOS.writeObject(o);
        ByteArrayInputStream BAIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(BAOS.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream OIS = new ObjectInputStream(BAIS);
        return OIS.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); return null;}
}
```

Comment: this does not work for KeyStores.